# sbt assembly issue java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65536

Tags: scala, sbt-assembly, fatjar

I am using `sbt-assembly` to package Scala software in a fat JAR. The software references a lot of libraries. When I run `sbt assembly` in the Windows command prompt, I meet the issue below. Anyone met this before?

```
sbt version: 1.2.8
sbt assembly version: 0.14.9
Java version:
version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Logs:

```
[info] Done packaging.
[error] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65536
[error]         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.createDebugLabel(ClassReader.java:2470)
[error]         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1661)
[error]         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1275)
[error]         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:679)
[error]         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
[error]         at org.pantsbuild.jarjar.MethodSignatureProcessor.process(MethodSignatureProcessor.java:53)
[error]         at org.pantsbuild.jarjar.util.JarProcessorChain.process(JarProcessorChain.java:38)
[error]         at org.pantsbuild.jarjar.MainProcessor.process(MainProcessor.java:116)
[error]         at org.pantsbuild.jarjar.JJProcessor.process(JJProcessor.scala:9)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Shader$.$anonfun$shadeDirectory$7(Shader.scala:102)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Shader$.$anonfun$shadeDirectory$7$adapted(Shader.scala:97)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Shader$.shadeDirectory(Shader.scala:97)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.$anonfun$assembleMappings$9(Assembly.scala:218)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AugmentedIterableIterator.map2combiner(RemainsIterator.scala:112)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AugmentedIterableIterator.map2combiner$(RemainsIterator.scala:109)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector$ParVectorIterator.map2combiner(ParVector.scala:62)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Map.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:1052)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.Task.$anonfun$tryLeaf$1(Tasks.scala:49)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Breaks$$anon$1.catchBreak(Breaks.scala:63)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.Task.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:52)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.Task.tryLeaf$(Tasks.scala:46)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Map.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:1049)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask.internal(Tasks.scala:166)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask.internal$(Tasks.scala:153)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.internal(Tasks.scala:436)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:146)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask.compute$(Tasks.scala:145)
[error]         at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:436)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
[error] (abc / assembly / assembledMappings) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65536
[error] Total time: 1029 s, completed Apr 24, 2020 3:27:19 PM
```

Comment: unexpected...do you happen to have some huge amount of classes? a class with a huge amount of methods? are you generating classes?

Comment: Yes, I think that reference class is huge. My solution is to move some method into my local library. That could be solve the issue. Any other suggestion?